# at grails.converters.XML.parse(XML.java:340) ~[grails-plugin-converters-3.0.17.jar:3.0.17]

Tags: grails, groovy

I implement a end point in my grails controller and try to pass xml data with postman

```
request.withFormat {
                xml {
                    println("Inside Xml")
                    // render "The XML Title Is ${request.XML.userId}."
                    println("XML: " + request.XML) // exception in this line
                }
}

at grails.converters.XML.parse(XML.java:340) ~[grails-plugin-converters-3.0.17.jar:3.0.17]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at grails.converters.XML.parse(XML.java:337)
```

I am using grails version 3.0.17

request.JSON is working fine but it throws error on request.XML

Below is the filters present on my controller

```
[pattern: '/demo/requests/**', filters: 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter,restTokenValidationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor'],
```

Comment: error sounds like your xml is incorrect - for example some tag not closed

Comment: xml is correct i validated it

Comment: I can't reproduce that. See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/chaitanyaguptaxml.  The code at https://github.com/jeffbrown/chaitanyaguptaxml/blob/7b9bacc7b18b2ec658d5e1419ddb3f8cb6bf7ff3/grails-app/controllers/chaitanyaguptaxml/DemoController.groovy#L7-L11 works.

Comment: @daggett FYI... I am not 100% sure but I don't think malformed xml would cause "Stream closed".  I see that more often when the body has already been read, for example by a filter/interceptor, or code to populate a command object with the body of the request before the user code executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something that is reading the body of the request before your `request.withFormat` method is invoked, that would explain the "Stream closed" error.

Common examples of that include a filter or interceptor in your app that is ready the body of the request before your controller action executes, and if the controller action accepts a command object, the body of the request has to be read before your code executes.

Comment: Still facing issue

Comment: "Still facing issue" -  I am sorry.  I have tried to reproduce the behavior and I cannot.  See the project that I linked in a comment under the question. If you can send a PR to that repo which demonstrates the problem or can share any project which demonstrates the problem, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we can investigate.  I am sorry for the trouble.

Comment: [pattern: '/demo/requests/**', filters: 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter,restTokenValidationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor'],

Comment: The above filters are present in my project

Comment: @chaitanyagupta I am sorry that I cannot reproduce the problem.  If you can share a project which demonstrates the problem I would be happy to help you investigate.

Comment: I resolved this issue by removing "restTokenValidationFilter" for that method